# UIMenuController didDismiss Method?

Tags: ios4, uitableview, ios5, uimenucontroller

I have a `UITableView` that has a didSelectRow method... it creates a `UIMenuController` and displays it.

Currently, it works correctly but when the UIMenuController dismisses I wanted to call a     `[tableView1 deselectRowAtIndexPath:path1 animated:YES];`

```
NSIndexPath *path1;
UITableView *table1;
#pragma maek - Table View
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    path1 = indexPath;

    tablview1 = tableview;

        CGRect location = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    location.origin.y = location.origin.y+30;

    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"View Item" action:@selector(viewItem:)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit Item" action:@selector(editItem:)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem3 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" action:@selector(cancelSubMenu:)];

    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menuController setTargetRect:location inView:self.view];
    menuController.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuItem, menuItem1,menuItem3, nil];

    menuController.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowUp;

    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)cancelSubMenu:(id)sender 
{
    [tableView1 deselectRowAtIndexPath:path1 animated:YES]; 
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder 
{
    return YES; 
}

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if(action == @selector(viewItem:)){return YES;}
    if(action == @selector(editItem:)){return YES;}
    if(action == @selector(cancelSubMenu:)){return YES;}

    return NO; 
}
```

When the user taps the cancel button on the `UIMenuController` the row is deselected properly.  But when the user taps anywhere else on the screen the `UIMenuControlller` dismisses but the row is still selected.

Is there some kind of didDismiss `UIMenuController` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIMenuController` will post a notification just after it hides called `UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification`, you can subscribe to this notification to call a method that in turn calls `deselectRowAtIndexPath` on your table view. for example:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethodHere) name:UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification object:nil];
```

And in Swift 5:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(self.receiveNotification(_:)),
                                       name: UIMenuController.didShowMenuNotification,
                                       object: nil)
```

And to handle the notification:

```
@objc func receiveNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    // do something here
}
```